# Do not repeat placeholders in the same string regex

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I made a regex to validate arrays that contain variable placeholders surrounded by *{* and *}*:

```
^(\/?(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]+)|(\{[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\}))\/?)*$
```

It will validate strings like `test/{a}/{b}` and `/some-text/{a}/{a}/` and its working fine. Here is the test: https://regex101.com/r/nP1tB2/2

Is it possible to block duplicated placeholders?

For example, in the 2nd string, `{a}` appears twice, but I would like to "block" (regex that doesn't match) it.

Comment: Try [`^(?!.*{([\w-]+)}.*{\1})(\/?(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)|(\{[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\}))\/?)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/mC4oG2/2).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew wow! i wouldn't have guessed in a milion years. Thanks pal

Comment: It would be useful if you could mention the regex flavor.

Comment: It will be used with PCRE, anready provided by reg101 ;)

Comment: Cool, that means `\w` will only match `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if `/u` modifier is not passed to the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to restrict the matching process:

```
^(?!.*{([\w-]+)}.*{\1})(\/?(([\w-]+)|(\{[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*\}))\/?)*$
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It means that right after a beginning of string is detected, `(?!.*{([\w-]+)}.*{\1})` will check if there are 0+ characters other than a newline followed with a `{...}` substring (with only letters, digits, underscores or hyphens) followed with the same pattern. If the pattern is found, the *whole match is failed*.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mC4oG2/3)

Note that *if* you do not use  a Unicode aware pattern (and it is not .NET without `RegexOptions.ECMAScript`), `\w` is equal to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. So, I replaced that with `\w` in your pattern. Else, restore that subpattern in both lookahead and the main pattern.

Also, `[a-zA-Z]` can also be expressed as `[^\W\d_]` or `\p{L}` (or even `[:alpha:]`) and `[a-zA-Z0-9]` as `[^\W_]` (or `[:alnum:]`, `[\p{L}\p{N}]`). These subpatterns are handy if you need to make the pattern Unicode aware. A lot depends on the regex flavor.